# Entity Framework: Associations do not get updated

Tags: c#, .net, associations

I know this is really a common problem but I have not been able to find a single solution to my problem.

I have an object 'edition' that holds a collection of 'page'. I am now trying to add a new page to an existing edition. The page is stored successfully but later when I am accessing the edition I still have the old amount of pages.

I tried the following when adding a new page:

```
var edition = context.Editions.Where(x => x.Id == editionId).FirstOrDefault();
context.Pages.AddObject(page);
edition.Pages.Add(page);
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(edition , System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I really don't have any idea what else I could be missing.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand, but  Are you trying remove page?

var edition = context.Editions.Where(x => x.Id == editionId).FirstOrDefault();
context.Pages.AddObject(page);
edition.Pages.Clear(); //Remove previuos pages
edition.Pages.Add(page);//Add new
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(edition , System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
context.SaveChanges();